How to I get another number from a random.randint in python?
I am trying to make a random number guesser game, and if the user gets it, I ask them if they want to play again. Problem is, if they say yes, the random number will be the same as it was last time. I am new to python and would really apprectate it if you could help me. Also, if there is anything I can inprove on, please tell me!
This is my code:
while True:
    i = 1
    import random
    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
       
    while 1 != 0:
        player_guess = input("Choose a number from 1-1000 ")
        if int(player_guess) == number:
            print("You got it!")
            i-1
            x = input("do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
            if x == "y":
                import random
                continue
            if x == "n":
                exit()
        elif int(player_guess) >= number:
            print("Too high!")
        elif int(player_guess) <= number:
            print("Too low!")



You don't need to import again. Use number = random.randint again

If they type "y", execute the number = random.randint(1, 1000) statement again.

Use import random once at the top of the program, don't keep reimporting.

while 1 != 0 do you expect this to ever be False?

What is the purpose of the i variable?  It is never used.

1 != 0: is always true so you can use while True: instead of while 1 != 0:

if you want to next game then you should exit inner loop while 1 != 0: using break instead of continue. Command continue goes to the beginning of loop while 1 != 0: but it doesn't exit it.

Generally, when in doubt, extract a [mcve]. In other words, reproduce the problem in isolation. That should have given you enough focus to find your own mistake.

You have to exist inner loop while 1 != 0 - and it needs break instead of continue.
Command continue goes to the beginning of current while 1 != 0 but it doesn't exit it .
import random  # PEP8: all imports at the beginning of code

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
       
    while True:
        player_guess = input("Choose a number from 1-1000 ")
        player_guess = int(player_guess)
        
        if player_guess == number:
            print("You got it!")
            
            x = input("do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
            x = x.lower() 
            
            if x == "y":
                break  # exit current loop
            elif x == "n":
                exit()
                
        elif player_guess >= number:
            print("Too high!")
        elif player_guess <= number:
            print("Too low!")


PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

BTW: If you would keep values 1, 1000 in variables then you could replace them after every answer and display e.g.from 250-1000 and  from 1-500 instead of always from 1-1000
import random  # PEP8: all imports at the beginning of code

while True:
    min_value = 1
    max_value = 1000

    number = random.randint(min_value, max_value)
    
    while True:
        player_guess = input(f"Choose a number from {min_value}-{max_value} ")
        player_guess = int(player_guess)
        
        if player_guess == number:
            print("You got it!")
            
            x = input("do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
            x = x.lower() 
            
            if x == "y":
                break
            elif x == "n":
                exit()
                
        elif player_guess >= number:
            max_value = player_guess-1
            print("Too high!")
        elif player_guess <= number:
            min_value = player_guess+1
            print("Too low!")


TL;DR: You should use break instead of continue. continue goes to the next iteration of the same loop; break exits the loop entirely.
Full answer:
The problem is your while loops. It seems you have two loops: one to regenerate the number, and the other to control the game. Your code is supposed to run the inner loop until the user guesses the correct answer, then break the inner loop and generate another number.
The problem is that the second loop never breaks. It just keeps running forever since every time your program reaches continue, it "continues" to the next iteration of the inner loop instead of letting the outer loop take another turn. The statement you want is break - read this article for the difference. Switching those out change should make your program work as expected.
This code should work:
import random

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 1000)

    while True:
        player_guess = int(input("Choose a number from 1-1000 "))

        if player_guess == number:
            print("You got it!")

            play_again = input("do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
            if play_again == "y":
                break
            if play_again == "n":
                exit()

        elif player_guess > number:
            print("Too high!")
        elif player_guess < number:
            print("Too low!")

Some other things I changed:

i wasn't doing anything, so I removed it. (Also, i-1 isn't how you decrement i - it should be i -= 1.
import random only needs to happen once. Put it at the top (outside of your while loop) and delete all other occurrence of it in your code.
while 1 != 0 is hard to read. Just write while True.
Writing int(player_guess) in every if statement is inefficient. Just wrap the input() call with int() so player_guess is an int from the start.
x is a confusing name for a variable. I changed it to play_again, which is more descriptive.
The code in if x == "y" doesn't do anything. import random only needs to be called once (see above), and continue just goes to the next iteration of the while != 0 loop. (Maybe you meant to write break instead? Either way,
You should be checking for > and < instead of >= or <= in your elif statements.


I think you've made two mistakes in your code, as I marked in the comments below:
while True:
    i = 1
    import random
    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
       
    while 1 != 0:  # i != 0
        player_guess = input("Choose a number from 1-1000 ")
        if int(player_guess) == number:
            print("You got it!")
            i-1  # i -= 1
            x = input("do you want to play again? (y/n) ")
            if x == "y":
                import random
                continue
            if x == "n":
                exit()
        elif int(player_guess) >= number:
            print("Too high!")
        elif int(player_guess) <= number:
            print("Too low!")

Also, about your coding style, there are several places that can be improved.

Use boolean variable to store whether player guesses the right number (you used variable i which takes value in 0 and 1).
Import modules at the begginging of your code.
Try to cover all possible cases. If user does not input an integer, or does not input y or n, your code may run into any results!

You may check this modified version of your code
import random

while True:
    guessed = False
    number = random.randint(1, 100)  # Change to 100 for convenience of tests
    
    while not guessed:
        player_input = input('Choose a number from 1 to 100: ')  # store the input in a variable
        
        try:
            player_guess = int(player_input)  # try to convert into an integer
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: invalid input')  # user did not input an integer
            continue

        if player_guess == number:
            print('You got it!')
            guessed = True

            user_input = input('Do you want to play again? (y/n) ')

            if user_input == 'y':
                continue
            else:
                exit()  # any input other than 'y' causes an exit
        elif player_guess > number:  # '=' is impossible, so use '>' instead of '>='
            print('Too high!')
        else:  # the only remaining case is '<', so 'elif' is redundant
            print('Too low!')

Actually, you can use continue and break to control the inner loop, so the boolean flag guessed can also be replaced.
import random

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 100)  # Change to 100 for convenience of tests
    
    while not guessed:
        player_input = input('Choose a number from 1 to 100: ')  # store the input in a variable
        
        try:
            player_guess = int(player_input)  # try to convert into an integer
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: invalid input')  # user did not input an integer
            continue  # use 'continue' to enter the next cycle of the inner loop

        if player_guess == number:
            print('You got it!')

            user_input = input('Do you want to play again? (y/n) ')

            if user_input == 'y':
                break  # use 'break' to exit the inner loop 
            else:
                exit()  # any input other than 'y' causes an exit
        elif player_guess > number:  # '=' is impossible, so use '>' instead of '>='
            print('Too high!')
        else:  # the only remaining case is '<', so 'elif' is redundant
            print('Too low!')

